# longest huffman codeword

Tags: huffman-code

I'm not quite sure how to determine what the longest possible codeword is under Huffman encoding for a specific set of frequencies?

Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a homework question?

Comment: Then you need to study Huffman encoding.

Answer (score 3):

For a specific set of frequencies?  Generate your tree, then see how tall it is...  If you're talking about in general, then it's something like N - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Abu-Mostafa and McEliece provide an answer in terms of the probability of the least frequent symbol.  The paper also has references to related work on similar questions.

http://tmo.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-110/110N.PDF